# Swagger-Codegen plugin does not generate @Deprecated annotation

Tags: swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I would like to set an annotation @deprecated on the endpoint which is generated by swagger-codegen plugin from a yaml file like:

```
 paths:
  '/debug-endpoint/v1/person/{id}':
    get:
      deprecated: true
      summary: get person info
      description: Get
      parameters:
        - name: Id
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string

......
```

with deprecated: true, it is shown in the swagger Ui editor, that the endpoint is deprecated, but in the generated code by swagger codegen, the @deprecated annotation is not set on the method.

Is it possible to set the @Deprecated annotation on the method which is generated by swagger codegen?

Comment: What server/client do you generate using Codegen?

Comment: I am facing a similar issue

Comment: has anyone made it past this issue?

Comment: any resolution for this?